# Shortcuts for align and equation?

Tags: macros

I've started using new command lately and I think it is great.  For example

```
\newcommand{\QQQ}{~~,\quad\text{and}\qquad }  
\newcommand{\WW}{~~,\quad\text{with}\qquad } 
\newcommand{\WWW}{~~,\quad\text{where}\qquad }
```

I also want to have a shortcut for creating equation and align envornments, but newcommand won't let me do it.  How can I make a shortcut for

```
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}?
```

I'm using TeXStudio if there's a non-latex way to do it in my editor.

For example, if I use

```
\newcommand{\ZZ }{\begin{align}} 
\newcommand{\ZZZ }{\end{align}}
```

and then type

```
\ZZ 
\pi
\ZZZ
```

I get the PDF compiler error:

```
Paragraph ended before \align was complete.
```

Comment: Why `\newcommand` would not work? What did you try that did not work? Can you add an example to show what you tried?

Comment: With `equation` it should work, but with `align` it doesn't because it scans for the `\end{align}` text, and with your attempt it fails to find it.  I must say, though, `\begin{align}` tells a lot more than `\ZZ` to me, and with some decent tab completion you can type `ba<TAB>` and get `\begin{align} ... \end{align}` typed (even fewer keystrokes than `\ZZ ... \ZZZ`)

Comment: My advice: don't use these shortcuts.  They seem to save time, but they actually cost you a lot more than they save (for starters, the time you spent asking this question)

Comment: The only option you have is to `\long\def\ZZ#1\ZZZ{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}`. This approach has been covered before.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible in LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}


\begin{luacode*}
local uppercase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
local lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
local numbers = "0123456789"
local char_set = uppercase .. lowercase .. numbers

function get_random_name(k)
    local tab = {}
    for i=1,k do
        local rand = math.random(char_set:len())
        table.insert(tab, char_set:sub(rand, rand))
    end
    return table.concat(tab,"")
end

function register_verbatim(cmd_e, env_name)
    local name = get_random_name(15)
    local env_s = string.format([[\begin{%s}]], env_name)
    local env_e = string.format([[\end{%s}]], env_name)
    tex.print(env_s)
    local callback = function(str)
        if string.find(str, cmd_e) then
            luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer" , name)
            return env_e
        else
            return str
        end
    end
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer" , callback, name)
end
\end{luacode*}


\newcommand{\al}{
    \directlua{
        register_verbatim([[\string\eal]], "align")
    }
}
\newcommand{\als}{
    \directlua{
        register_verbatim([[\string\eals]], "align*")
    }
}

\begin{document}

\al
\int_a^b
\eal

\als
\frac{a}{b}
\eals

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not only possible in LuaTeX. It is possible in plain TeX or LaTeX too. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\def\al#1\eal{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
\def\als#1\eals{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}}

\begin{document}
    
\al
\int_a^b
\eal

\als
\frac{a}{b}
\eals

\end{document}
```